# Copy and set-mark in Bash as in Emacs?

Tags: bash, line-editor, inputrc

I would like to be able to copy and paste text in the command line in Bash using the same keyboard bindings that Emacs uses by default (i.e. using `C-space` for `set-mark`, `M-w` to copy text, `C-y`, `M-y` to paste it, etc.).

The [GNU Bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Line-Editing) says that Bash comes with some of these key bindings set up by default.

For example, yanking (`C-y`) works by default on my terminal. However, I can't get the `set-mark` and `copy` commands to work, and they don't seem to be bound to any keys by default.

Usually, the way a user can define her own key bindings is to add them to `.inputrc`. So I looked and found the following bash functions in the documentation that I presume can help me define the Emacs-like behavior that I want (i.e. `set-mark` with `C-space` and `copy` with `M-w`).

```
copy-region-as-kill ()
```

> Copy the text in the region to the
>   kill buffer, so it can be yanked right
>   away. By default, this command is
>   unbound.

and

```
set-mark (C-@)
```

> Set the mark to the point. If a
>   numeric argument is supplied, the mark
>   is set to that position.

If I understand correctly, the above means that `copy-region-as-kill` is not bound to any keyboard sequence by default, while `set-mark` is bound to `C-@` by default.

I tried `C-@` on my terminal, but I don't think it runs `set-mark` because I don't see any text highlighted when I move my cursor. In any case, I tried adding  keyboard bindings (`M-w` and `C-`) to the functions  `copy-region-as-kill` and `set-mark` above in my `.inputrc` and then reloading it with `C-x C-r`, but this didn't work. I know that my other entries in `.inputrc` work because I have other user-defined keybindings defined in it.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Am I missing anything?

Comment: What version of `bash` and what terminal program are you using?

Comment: I'm using
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

on gnome-terminal (also on Terminator)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't highlight the selection, but otherwise I think it works fine.

Try running

```
$ bind -p | grep copy-region-as-kill
```

to make sure that `C-x C-r` actually worked.

It should say:

```
"\ew": copy-region-as-kill
```

After that, it should work fine.

Example:

```
$ abc<C-Spc><C-a><M-w> def <C-y>
```

gives me

```
$ abc def abc
```

If you ever want to know where `mark` is, just do `C-x` `C-x`.

Example:

```
$ <C-Spc>abc<C-x><C-x>
```

will put the cursor back to where you set mark (the start of the line).

Also, I don't think you need to add the `set-mark` binding.  I didn't.

```
$ bind -p | grep set-mark
"\C-@": set-mark
"\e ": set-mark
# vi-set-mark (not bound)
```

(note that most terminals send `C-@` when `C-Spc` is pressed.   I assume yours does too.)

If all this fails:

- does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> work in `emacs -nw` on the same terminal?
- do other <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd> shortcuts work in bash?

Comment: Thanks! I had "M-w" instead of "\ew" in .inputrc. The lack of highlighting also confused me. Thanks for the pointer to the bind command by the way. It now works like a charm!

Comment: Welcome!  Yeah, you have to write `\e` or `\M-`.  See [readline init file syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax).

Comment: What a great answer!  Thanks.  This cleared up similar issues for me :D

Comment: set-mark and copy-region-as-kill work silently, can I highlight the region (as in emacs)?

Answer (score 4):

I also bind C-w for **kill-region**. Here my .inputrc:

```
# See http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2009-03/msg00033.html
set bind-tty-special-chars off

# Define my favorite Emacs key bindings.
"\C-@": set-mark
"\e ": set-mark
"\C-w": kill-region
"\ew": copy-region-as-kill
"\e/": dabbrev-expand
```