# Adding more Emacs-like bindings to ZSH's line editor (ZLE)

Tags: zsh, line-editor

I have a couple of questions regarding the emacs-like keyboard bindings in Zsh. As background to all the questions: I have Emacs-like keybinding activated with `bindkey -e` (activated by default)

#### Copying and region highlighting:

In Emacs, if you run `C-space` (`set-mark`), select a region and then copy it using `M-w`, Emacs puts the region in the kill ring and stops selecting text (i.e. if I move the point, no more text is selected).

However, I can't get the same behavior in [ZLE](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html). Once I copy a region with `M-W`, the selection mode is still on, and if I move my cursor, the selection keeps changing.

#### Stop selection:

In Emacs, if I am selecting a region, and press `C-g`, the selection stops (the current mark is killed). In Zsh, by default, `C-g` starts a new line in the shell. So is there a ZLE command that I can bind to (maybe using something different from `C-g`) to stop an ongoing selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deactivate the selection, run [`set-mark-command`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-set_002dmark_002dcommand) with a negative argument: `ESC - Ctrl+Space`.

To copy the region and deactivate the selection, write a function that performs the two actions, then [declare it as a widget with `zle -N`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-defining-widgets) and [bind](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-bindkey) that widget to a key.

```
copy-region-as-kill-deactivate-mark () {
  zle copy-region-as-kill
  zle set-mark-command -n -1
}
zle -N copy-region-as-kill-deactivate-mark
bindkey '\ew' copy-region-as-kill-deactivate-mark
```

Comment: hi Gilles, when i run `set-mark-command` in zsh and move the cursor left/right, will it markup the selected text in black bgcolor... i am not seeing such highlighting in my zsh/gnome terminal...  In bash as well, @http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11933/copy-and-set-mark-in-bash-as-in-emacs Mikel has said, bash doesn't do highlighting....